# React Native PanResponder slow

Tags: react-native, flutter

I have a 300x300 orange View that can receive pan events using PanResponder. I have 100 circles that can be moved around together in this view. Each circle is rendered in my "Node" component when onPanResponderMove is called.

The code is ok for one circle but when there are 100 it lags. If panning quickly, there can be up to a 2s delay after touch is released where the circles continue to draw.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, PanResponder} from 'react-native'

class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <ReactSurface />
    }
}

class ReactSurface extends React.Component {

    constructor (props){
        super(props)
        console.log('ReactSurface constructor')

        this.onTouchStart = this.onTouchStart.bind(this)
        this.onTouchMove = this.onTouchMove.bind(this)
        this.onTouchEnd = this.onTouchEnd.bind(this)

        this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
            onPanResponderStart: this.onTouchStart,
            onPanResponderMove: this.onTouchMove,
            onPanResponderRelease: this.onTouchEnd,
        })

        this.coordinates = []
        for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            this.coordinates.push(2*i)
        }

        this.state = {
            xAxisY: 0,
            yAxisX: 0,
        }
    }

    onTouchStart(){
        console.log('onTouchStart')
        this.startYAxisX = this.state.yAxisX
        this.startXAxisY = this.state.xAxisY
    }

    onTouchMove(e, gestureState) {
        console.log('onTouchMove')
        this.setState({
            yAxisX: this.startYAxisX + gestureState.dx,
            xAxisY: this.startXAxisY + gestureState.dy
        })
    }

    onTouchEnd() {
        console.log('onTouchEnd')
    }

    render(){
        return(<View 
            {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>

            <View style={{
                backgroundColor: 'orange',
                position: 'absolute',
                width:300,
                height:300,
                }}>

                <AllNodes 
                    xAxisY={this.state.xAxisY}
                    yAxisX={this.state.yAxisX}
                    nodeRad={25}
                    coordinates={this.coordinates}/>

            </View>      
        </View>)
    }
}

const AllNodes = props => {
    return props.coordinates.map((value, index) => {
        return <Node key={index}
            rawX={value} rawY={value}
            yAxisX={props.yAxisX} xAxisY={props.xAxisY}
            nodeRad={props.nodeRad}/>
    })
}

const Node = props => {
    return <View style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: props.xAxisY + props.rawY - props.nodeRad,
        left: props.yAxisX + props.rawX - props.nodeRad,
        width: 2*props.nodeRad,
        height: 2*props.nodeRad,
        borderRadius: props.nodeRad,
        borderWidth: 1,
    }}/>
}

export default App
```

**How can I make my PanResponder significantly faster?**

*Note: If I can't I'm considering switching to the Flutter framework as it is efficient at drawing.*

Edit: here is a link to a video of the panning on react-native and flutter
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OgvHkf56Ru_I1NVooIrqby1hy5WtSIVR

Comment: As a Flutter developer, that's definitely something you can do without performance issue. But not however you like. You'll need a bit of understanding in the framework to have ideal performances.

Comment: You setState on each move - that's why your code is slow. Use Animated.Value instead